# How can I increase volume beyond max in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, volume-control

How can I increase the volume beyond the maximum in xubuntu, (preferably without using anything from gnome)?

Something similar to what you have in gnome on ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
and adjust to suit

[image]

Comment: When I launched pavucontrol (11.04 here), the volume was already at 90%, so I didn't get much of a boost. Any way to increase it further? When I play some files, they are very loud, with others, they are quiet even at max volume. This is very annoying.

Comment: problem with this solution is that everytime you change the volume you have to do that all over again