# How to make sound output volume above 100% permanently

Tags: 12.04, unity, indicator-sound

My sound level is very low on my laptop. To coup with it  I regularly put it above 100% in sound output volume(SUV) to make things better:[image: general sound settings]

I wonder if there is solution to make my SUV 110% by default. So that when I put my sound level to the max next time it will be 10% louder.

[image]

Comment: Does your audio device have a Parliament which you've surrounded with tanks? That being said, pavucontrol, as suggested by fleamour, is a good bet.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219739/adjust-max-possible-volume-in-pulseaudio

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `pavucontrol` from Synaptic Package Manager. It's worth a shot, my volume is remembered between cold boots since installing it.

Comment: I have tried it, but still can't figure out how to preserve volume above 100% by default. After moving volume slide back and forth to max on second picture, it alas at 100% not at desirable 110%.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/111930/how-can-i-increase-volume-beyond-max-in-xubuntu