# Increase Sound level beyond 100%

Tags: 13.04, sound

Is it possible to set the default sound level more than 100%?

Every time after booting I've to manually increase the sound level from the sound settings which is a bit irritating.

I am using `Ubuntu 13.04`

Comment: Are you able to manually increase it above 100? How? Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111930/how-can-i-increase-volume-beyond-max-in-xubuntu, http://askubuntu.com/questions/219739/adjust-max-possible-volume-in-pulseaudio

Comment: yes it does. but the sound quality deteriorates. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), you can set sound level as you wish:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

In this case we have set the volume of the sink #0 to 150%.

Now, if you want to set this setting as default at startup, add the above command in `/etc/rc.local` file. You can use `sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local` to open an edit this file:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 150%

exit 0
```

Comment: ...and if I want it back to normal I execute `pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 100%` ??

Comment: (that's the default right?)

Comment: @MinaMichael Right!

Comment: awesome! I did not have my headphones with me and this one liner has let me continue my learning again :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, you can simply open Settings and after that search for "sound" or just click on the Sound tab on the left side of the Settings panel.
After that press "Over-Amplification" and change your max sound volume to more than 100%
(more details on the screenshot below)

[Sound volume up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkUF3.png)

Comment: It only goes up to 150% though. The accepted answer can go beyond that.

Comment: that's fanny, @bwdm because it's a hack in the accepted answer and you can kill your sound card or something else, if you'll use a sound level of more than 150%, it's unsafe and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Sample output:

```
0  SymbolicNameHere  value value value valueHz  RUNNING
```

To increase volume:

```
 pactl set-sink-volume SymbolicNameHere value%
```

Supporting Answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565397/430146