# Make my audio louder Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

I have an Asus tp500l laptop. On windows 8 and 10 my audio sound was much louder i guess it was because of the windows update but i'm not sure wich audio driver was installed. is there a way to get the same quality audio as in windows?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Answer (score 10):

You can increase volume by cliciking "Allow more that 100% at

System Settings -> Sound

Comment: This setting seems to be gone in 2022, at least in Ubuntu Budgie / Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have yet to reply to @Fabby with the requested post edit on yr hw info, I just will assume you use a PulseAudio sound server on your Trusty Tahr...

In that config you can use `pactl`. (Please lookup `man pactl` in the terminal). From the man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    pactl  can  be  used  to  issue  control commands to the PulseAudio sound
>    server.
> ```

As already suggested [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322486/increase-sound-level), using `pactl`, you can tweak your sound temporarily or permanently. Before commiting to a permanent change: try it in your session by typing in terminal (`CTRL+ALT+T`):

```
$ pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

and play with your sound controls.  If you are satisfied go on to the excellent permanent solution proposed by @Radu_Rădeanu as referenced above. 
I have not had a chance to try it myself on 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if what you really need is to feel music louder, you can use `pulseeffects` on Ubuntu.

Install:

```sh
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

Run:

```
pulseeffects
```

This is the configuration I've ended up myself at Kubuntu 20.04:

[image]

`Base Enhancer` makes bass louder.

[image]

`Cryslalizer` makes mid and high frequencies sound better.

[image]

`Auto Gain` is able to make sound louder when it is present, because it is able to detect silence.

[image]

`Maximizer` always makes sound to feel louder, but more importantly, it intelligently reduces volume to protect audio from clipping. So there is no artificial noise in the audio.

Be sure your audio pipeline has the same order for enabled audio effects to get the best experience.