# Will setting the volume above 100% hurt my speakers?

Tags: sound, 20.04, music

So, I was vibing to Sasageyo and wanted to increase the volume above 100%. I found this: [Increase Sound level](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322486/increase-sound-level). I followed the first answer and it works perfectly fine, though, I was wondering if it hurts my speakers in any way, because of keeping the volume too high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it wont hurt, but you should take into consideration that 100% means -10dbV, which is about 0.3 V alternate output voltage. [More infos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) This is a standard. If you connect your output to an pre-amplifier, the -10dbV level is the base on which the circuit has been designed.
Increasing the output will lead to distortion. It might even produce a small DC current which will hurt the speakers (or better its coils), depending on how powerful your amplifier is, which will amplify the -10dbV signal to much higher voltages.
That said it doesn't really matter if you increase the volume further up when no powerful amplifier is involved.